# Customize Search Terms search criteria of the view

Tags: views

I am having a weird problem. I have made a exposed Filter "Search" field which allows a user to Search the results. It's a Search Term.

The problem is that it is not searching the results effectively.

**Example:** If I have a title **XYZ-0123** and I search for **XYZ**, it would not give this result.

Any idea how I can customize the Search Term?

I'd greatly appreciate if you can assist here.

### Here is a screenshot of the pop up in view. You can see there's no indication.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select **Containg any word** operator in expose filter settings of Title field.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no indication of operator here on search terms pop in my view. I uploaded a screenshot above.